# Condition under which one can extend a linearly independent set in a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module to a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, free-groups

I'm having difficulty answering the following simple (?) question:

Let $X = \mathbb{Z}^n$, and let $M$ be a submodule of $X$ closed under division - by which I mean that if $x \in X$ has $n x \in M$ for some integer $n$, then $x \in M$.

I want to know:

1) Is $M$ complemented in $X$? (That is, is $M$ a direct summand as $\mathbb{Z}$-module?) (The usual counter example showing the difference between $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and vector spaces $2\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ does not pass my criterion.)

2) If so, how do I find the complement? (I.e. produce from a basis for $M$ a basis for the complement.)

I am asking for a condition under which one can extend a linearly independent set in a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module to a basis, and I am guessing that that condition is that the span is closed under division in the way described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the short exact sequence $$0\to M\to X \to X/M \to 0.$$ Your divisibility condition essentially says that $X/M$ is torsion free. Thus, $X/M$ is free and the sequence splits, i.e., $X\cong M \oplus X/M$.

Comment: Awesome. I was not thinking anything like this! I guess this is also very computable, at least in principal (the part that gives me pause is finding a basis for $X/M$, but presumably if I went back through the proof of torsion free finitely generated abelian groups are free I would see how to do it). One question: Do we need finite generatedness for the general statement? (I know we do for your argument, because of horrible monsters like $\mathbb{Q}$) That is, is there an (infinitely generated) free abelian group and a "closed under division" subgroup which is not complemented?

Comment: Yes we do need finite generatedness. Take $X=\bigoplus_{q \in \Bbb{Q}} \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Q}$ to be the canonical surjective map and construct a short exact sequence $K \to X \to \Bbb{Q}$ from it. Since $\Bbb{Q}$ is torsion free, $K<X$ is closed under division. But the sequence doesn't split, because otherwise, $\Bbb{Q}$ would be a direct summand of a free module and would thus be projective. But it is not.